# How can I change where unix pipe sends its results for the split command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pipe

Basically I'm doing this:

```
export_something | split -b 1000
```

which splits the results of the export into files names xaa, xab, xac all 1000 bytes each

but I want my output from split to go into files with a specific-prefix. Ordinarily I'd just do this:

```
split -b <file> <prefix>
```

but there's no flag for prefix when you're piping to it. What I'm looking for is a way to do this:

```
export_something | split -b 1000 <output-from-pipe> <prefix>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, `-` is commonly used to denote stdin or stdout, whichever makes more sense. In your example

```
export_something | split -b 1000 - <prefix>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use - for input

> Output fixed-size  pieces of INPUT to
> PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...;
>
> default size
> is 1000 lines, and default PREFIX is
> `x'.
>
> With no INPUT, or  when INPUT is
> -, read standard input.

```
export_something | split -b 1000 - <prefix>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `-` as input as `split --help` says

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inline expression (or whatever it's called, I can never remember) to export the data directly into the function as a string:

```
 split -b 1000 "`export_something`" <prefix>
```

Hope this works.

Comment: No, that would take the contents as the filename.  What you're thinking of is "process substitution": `split -b 1000 <(export_something) prefix`

Comment: Oh, okay. I never used `split`, so now I know that it can't take a direct text argument... Thanks for the info, though. Now I know how to do that!